# Determine the Fourier Transform and Fourier Series of the function

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

$$
f(t)=\frac{\sin(at)}{t}
$$

Since the term is parameterized, it's easy to see that if I take the first derivative with respect to 'a', then the function becomes considerably easier.  I do this to the Fourier Transform and obtain:
$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\Im (f(t))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\cos(at))e^{itx}dt
$$

However, this is an integral of an even function times an odd function, which equals 0 and raises my suspicion.  I've tried implementing Euler's cosine form and got nowhere.

Also I'm using the imaginary symbol as the Fourier transform.  Why?  It looks cool.

Comment: Is the complex exponential an odd function ?

Answer (score 2):

The differentiating inside the integral trick requires several conditions be checked first.  If you notice, the integral on the right is not even defined.

Check out http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf

and [The Integral that Stumped Feynman?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253910/the-integral-that-stumped-feynman)

Also you have to be a bit careful with how you're defining everything.  You should call the Fourier transform $\hat{f}(x)$ rather than $f(t)$ since it is a different function in the variable $x$.

Comment: Edited for definition

Comment: I'll take a look at the link

Comment: That first link also has a version of the integral you are interested in.  They choose a different parameter to differentiate with respect to so that the function is dominated by $|e^{-bt}|$

Comment: I see it now.  Took the derivative to the wrong one.  Sorry, for the late reply, I'm working on about 10 other things for students tomorrow.

Comment: @muzzlator : the integral on the right is very well defined in the [best integration theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral).