# Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{\sqrt[4]{P(\cos t,\sin t)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> $${\LARGE\int}_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{\sqrt[{\LARGE 4}]{A\Big(\sin^8t+\cos^8t\Big)+B\Big(\sin^6t\cos^2t+\sin^2t\cos^6t\Big)+C~\sin^4t\cos^4t}}~=~?$$

where $A=0.3$, $B=-3.3$, and $C=10$. Its numerical value is about $12.0165220075768590.$

The Inverse Symbolic Calculator seems baffled. Maple and Mathematica are both unable to

return a closed form. $\bigg($Feel free to choose $A=\dfrac13$ and $B=-\dfrac{10}3$ , if it helps$\bigg)$.

---

**Motivation:**

[image]

$\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad$ The above shape is given by the implicit polynomial equation $$A\Big(x^8+y^8\Big)+B\Big(x^6y^2+x^2y^6\Big)+C~x^4y^4=R^8,$$ where $A=0.3$, $B=-3.3$, $C=10$, and $R=2$. Letting $x=r\sin t$ and $y=r\cos t$, we are finally able to express it in polar coordinates, since the Cartesian ones seem somewhat inadequate, given its extremely concave shape, which render it quite resistant to being parsed in terms of single-value functions, despite various sectionings and rotations. [Thus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Integral_calculus_.28area.29) the afore-mentioned integral is born. But whether it possesses a closed form, even one in terms of special functions, such as elliptic integrals, is beyond me. I don't really see the tangent half-angle substitution going anywhere. Perhaps some complex integration methods are in order ?

Comment: Let's use W|A to do the painful trig simplification. I'll use $A=3/10$, $B=-33/10$, this gives the radicand as
$$
\frac{1}{320} (45+8 \cos(4 t)+43 \cos(8 t)),
$$
which I think you'll agree is a decent improvement. The integral becomes 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2^{3/2} \sqrt[4]{5} \ \mathrm{d}t}{(45+8 \cos(4 t)+43 \cos(8 t))^{1/4}}.
$$

Comment: Another idea is that $$45 + 43 \cos(8 t) = 2 + 43 + 43\cos^2(4t) - 43\sin^2t = 2+86\cos^2t$$
which changes the integral further, into 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{2 \sqrt[4]{5} \ \mathrm{d}t}{(1+4 \cos(4 t)+43 \cos^2(4 t))^{1/4}}.
$$

Comment: I didn't use W|A. I managed to reduce it to
$$4\cdot (156)^{1/4}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dx}{((13\sin^2x-7)^2+3)^{1/4}}$$
But I have no idea about the next step.

Comment: @PranavArora: Substituting $x=4t$ and then completing the square seems like a very good idea, but I'm afraid that the coefficients of your expression, at least in its current form, are incorrect.

Comment: @Lucian: Sorry but I think my expression is correct. The expression Bennett Gardiner posted gives a value 10.0533 and my expression gives 11.0733 which is much closer to the answer you posted in OP.

Comment: BTW, did you evaluate the expression using A=0.3 and B=-3.3 or A=1/3 and B=-10/3?

Comment: @PranavArora: Bennett's expressions are equivalent with the original integral, since both can be decomposed into the same polynomial expression in $\sin x$ (or $\cos x$), and yield the same numerical result. Either way, yours is conceptually correct.

Comment: @PranavArora: OK, I got it now: Yours fits numerically for the second case, with the simpler values for A and B.

Comment: Any ideas about proceeding with the integral? Does it involve special functions? If so, I give up. :P

Comment: @PranavArora: I have *no* idea. For now, only a couple of ideas come to mind: the Weierstrass tangent half-angle substitution, $t=\sin x$, or $t=\sin^2x$. I'll have to explore all three, and see where they might lead, before forming any opinion on the subject.

Comment: This question made me remember this http://math.stackexchange.com/a/431366/78722

I imagine it'd be difficult (impossible?) to come up with the correct function $f$, however.

Comment: I think this question is possible. How do you feel about answers involving constants that are roots of a polynomial but can't be expressed in terms of radicals?

Comment: @Brad: No problem, as long as the polynomials in question are mentioned explicitly, and enough identifying characteristics of the root are described; e.g., the real root of $x^5-x-1=0$.

Comment: It simply escapes me why someone is desiring a "closed" expression for an seemingly impossible integral, if a sufficient numerical approximation is available already. What do you expect? At best, some complicated formula will be obtained. In the end, you have to substitute numerical values into that formula and evaluate, with the same outcome the you already have. So what's the big deal?

Comment: @HandeBruijn: Mathematical affinities, just like almost any other inclinations out there, are, at their core, something deeply irrational and unexplainable. The ashes of our ancestors, for instance, are virtually indistinguishable from those of someone else's. Just like $\pi$ is, for all intents and purposes, practically identical with the rational quantity $3.1416$. Nevertheless, no one replaces the remains of their forefathers with those belonging to others, or goes to mourn at the graves of complete strangers. Ultimately, it's all a question of *identity*. The same with numbers.

Comment: I have something that might be of interest. I am typing it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the several equivalent integrals already published, this one is of interest :
$${\LARGE\int}_0^{\infty}\frac{4~dt}{\sqrt[{\LARGE 4}]{4A\cosh^2t+2B\cosh t+C-2A}}$$
Suppose that a closed form exists for this integral. By "closed form" I mean the combination of a limited number of standard functions. This closed form must be valid for particular values of $A,B,C$, for example $A=1/4, B=1/2, C=1/2$, i.e. the integral :
$${\LARGE\int}_0^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\sqrt[{\LARGE 4}]{\cosh^2t+\cosh t}}$$
As far as I know, there is no closed form for it, which is in contradiction with the above supposition. That is the reason why I think that it is doubtful that a closed form exists for the first integral. May be, it might exists a closed form involving other special functions not referenced or not today considered as standard function in the publications.

Comment: $(+1)$ for finding a beautiful alternate expression, and for the pertinent insight. Also, see Brad's ongoing work, and feel free to share your thoughts, if you like.

Answer (score 5):

This post is a work in progress and I still have a lot of work to do in terms of formatting, showing work and the final evaluation of the integral. I have used contour integration to reduce the integral to an integral involving only polynomials. If you have any questions feel free to ask.

Let $\gamma$ be the unit$\require{autoload-all}$ circle.

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi}\!\!\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt[4]{A(\sin^8(t)+\cos^8(t))+B(\sin^6(t)\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t)\cos^6(t))+C\sin^4(t)\cos^4(t)}}$$

$$
\toggle{ 
\text{Set} \; x = e^{it}\quad\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click for Information }}
}{
\begin{align}
 x &= e^{it}\\
\sin(t) &= \frac{1}{2i}\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
\cos(t) &=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\\
\mathrm{d}t &= \frac{-i \, \mathrm{d}x}{x}
\end{align}
}\endtoggle
$$

$$I = \int_\gamma\!\frac{-i\,\mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt[4]{A((x-\frac{1}{x})^8+(x+\frac{1}{x})^8)-B((x-\frac{1}{x})^6(x+\frac{1}{x})^2+(x-\frac{1}{x})^2(x+\frac{1}{x})^6)+C(x^2-\frac{1}{x^2})^4}}$$

---

We will let $$P'(x) = A\left(\left(\!x-\frac{1}{x}\!\right)^8\!\!+\left(\!x+\frac{1}{x}\!\right)^8\right) \!-B\left(\!x^2\!-\!\frac{1}{x^2}\!\right)^2\!\left(\left(\!x-\frac{1}{x}\!\right)^4\!\!+\left(\!x+\frac{1}{x}\!\right)^4\right)\! + C\left(\!x^2\!-\!\frac{1}{x^2}\!\right)^4$$

and $$P(x) = 256\cdot P'(x)$$

---

$$I = \int_\gamma \! \frac{-4i}{x\sqrt[4]{P(x)}} \mathrm{d}x$$

We will now proceed to evaluate the integral using contour methods. A careful note suggests that $P(x)$ can be solved like a quartic in $x^4$. Let the roots of this polynomial be $\xi_j$ for $1\leq j \leq 16$. Note that the function we are integrating tends to $0$ as $x\to 0$.

For any given sets of parameters, find the roots and use the theory of contour integration to evaluate the integral. This could be possible in the general case but most likely not worth pursuing.

---

With this we should be able to find a somewhat closed form for your specific case.

For your parameters, $$\begin{align}P(x) =\frac{86 x^8}{5}+\frac{86}{5 x^8}+\frac{16 x^4}{5}+\frac{16}{5 x^4}+36 \end{align}$$

Because it shares the same roots as a quartic in $x^4$ it admits roots expressible in terms of radicals. 
$$
\toggle{\enclose{roundedbox}{\text{ Click for Analysis of Roots }}
}{
\text{For simplicity, define}\\
 \Omega_1 = \Re\left(-\frac{2}{43}-\frac{i \sqrt{39}}{43}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{7536}{1849}+\frac{16 i \sqrt{39}}{1849}}\right)  \approx -0.0398198141\\ 
\Omega_2 =\Im\left(-\frac{2}{43}-\frac{i \sqrt{39}}{43}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{7536}{1849}+\frac{16 i \sqrt{39}}{1849}}\right) \approx 0.8642098747 \\
\Omega_3 = \Re\left(-\frac{2}{43}+\frac{i \sqrt{39}}{43}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{7536}{1849}-\frac{16 i \sqrt{39}}{1849}}\right) \approx -0.0532034417\\
\Omega_4 = \Im\left(-\frac{2}{43}+\frac{i \sqrt{39}}{43}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{7536}{1849}-\frac{16 i \sqrt{39}}{1849}}\right) \approx 1.1546748979 \\
\text{The roots are given by}\\
\begin{align}
\zeta_{1-4} &= (\Omega_1+i\Omega_2 )^{1/4}e^{k\pi i/2}\\
\zeta_{5-8} &= (\Omega_1-i\Omega_2 )^{1/4}e^{k\pi i/2}\\
\zeta_{9-12} &= (\Omega_3+i\Omega_4 )^{1/4}e^{k\pi i/2}\\
\zeta_{13-16} &= (\Omega_3-i\Omega_4 )^{1/4}e^{k\pi i/2}\\
\end{align}\\
\text{for}\; k = 0,1,2,3.
}\endtoggle
$$

It is clear that $8$ of these roots ($\zeta_{1-8}\!$) are inside the contour.

Now consider
$$I = \int_\gamma \! \frac{-4i}{x\sqrt[4]{P(x)}} \mathrm{d}x$$

We are now looking for a different way of evaluating this integral.

This integral will be split into many contours that include, the unit circle, small semi-circles around each root of $P(x)$ inside the unit circle, lines connecting the unit circle to the roots and lines connecting the roots to the origin. For a better idea of what contour I am describing, see the image at the bottom of the post.

It is good to note that the contribution from the small circles around each root is zero because the function tends to $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{z}}$ around the roots.  Additionally, the total contribution of the lines connecting the unit circle to the root will be zero because it is the same path traversed in the opposite direction. This is not the case for the other lines because of the branch cut.

We can now write that the final result, $I$, is equal to the sum of the integrals that connect the roots to the origin. For a simplification,

$$\begin{align} \Omega_1 &= -\frac{2}{43}-\frac{i \sqrt{39}}{43}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{-\frac{7536}{1849}+\frac{16 i \sqrt{39}}{1849}}\\[.2cm] \xi &= \Omega_1^{1/4} \approx 0.8867082411 + 0.3793025249 i\end{align}$$

$\xi$ is one of the roots of $P(x)$. Using symmetry, which will be justified later, we find that

$$\large J = \int_0^1\!\!\! \frac{32 i}{t \sqrt[4]{\frac{86}{5}t^8\xi^8+\frac{86}{5 t^8 \xi^8}+\frac{16}{5} t^4\xi^4+\frac{16}{5 t^4 \xi^4}+36}} \mathrm{d}t$$

$$\large I = 12.01652200\ldots = \boxed{\Re({J}) + \Im({J})}$$

For numerical evidence

> In :=
>
> w= N[(-(2/43)-(I Sqrt[39])/43+1/2 Sqrt[-(7536/1849)+(16 I Sqrt[39])/1849])^(1/4),100]
>
> J=  NIntegrate[(32 I)/(t (36+86/(5 t^8 w^8)+16/(5 t^4 w^4)+16/5 t^4 w^4+86/5 t^8 w^8)^(1/4)),{t,0,1},WorkingPrecision->50];
>
> Re[J]+Im[J]
>
> Out :=   12.016522007576859017247019246788042118792983861776

---

The next step is to find a simpler form for $J$. The most natural substitution is that of $x = t\xi$. With this, write

$$\begin{align} J &= 32 i\int_0^\xi\!\!\! \frac{ \mathrm{d}x}{x\sqrt[4]{\frac{86}{5}x^8+\frac{86}{5x^8}+\frac{16}{5} x^4+\frac{16}{5x^4}+36}} \\[.2cm] &= 32i \cdot 5^{1/4} \int_0^\xi \!\!\! \frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{86x^{16}+16x^{12}+180x^8+16x^4+86}}\mathrm{d}x\end{align}$$

This result may not seem satisfactory but I have turned the trigonometric integral into one involving only polynomials. This post is a work in progress so I may be able to find a nicer form for the integral in the coming time.

---

For the reasoning behind my choice of contour, see this picture. The $16$ roots are located at the tips of the white lines with the white lines being the branch cuts. Due to aforementioned simplification, the final integral is equal to the sum of the integrals along the white lines in the unit circle. Symmetry can be used to simplify the final evaluation.

[image]

Here is the code used to generate this image (stolen from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34090)).

> GraphicsRow[Table[ContourPlot[g[f],{x,-1.5,1.5},{y,-1.5,1.5},ColorFunction->"GrayYellowTones",Epilog->{Cyan,Thick,Circle[{0,0}],Red,PointSize[0.02],Point[{Re@#,Im@#}&/@{}]},Contours->100],{g,{Re,Im}}]]

Comment: If the mathematica code gives any trouble try replacing the arrow with `->`.

Comment: $(+1)$ for the great work! The grace period, starting in $3$ hours, lasts for an entire day, so there's still plenty of time.

Comment: $y=x^2$ seems like an obvious substitution in the last integral.

Comment: This seems way too complicated. Notice
$$\sqrt[4]{P(t)} = |\sin t\cos t| \sqrt[4]{A \left( \tan^4 t + \frac{1}{\tan^4 t} \right)
+ B \left( \tan^2 t + \frac{1}{\tan^2 t}\right) + C}$$

Since $\displaystyle\;\frac{d\tan t}{\tan t} = \frac{dt}{\sin t\cos t}\;$,
if one define $\;z = \tan t\;$ for $t \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, we have
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{\sqrt[4]{P(t)}}
= 4 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{dt}{\sqrt[4]{P(t)}}
= 4 \int_0^\infty \frac{dz}{z\sqrt[4]{A (z^4 + z^{-4} ) + B(z^2 + z^{-2}) + C}}\\
= 4 \int_0^\infty \frac{dz}{\sqrt[4]{A (z^8 + 1 ) + B(z^6 + z^2) + Cz^4}}
$$

Comment: @achillehui That is a very slick way of finding the integral. I regret that the thought of contour integration came to me before a tangent substitution. Do you think that either my or your integral is likely to have a closed form?

Comment: @Brad: I've checked the two parts $($real and imaginary$)$ of the complex integral with the *Inverse Symbolic Calculator*, both with and without the $\sqrt[4]5$ present, but came up empty handed.

Comment: @Brad I doubt there is a closed form for this. The major problem is the $\sqrt[4]{\ldots}$ part. There are not too many algebraic identities known among special functions that involve radicals other than square roots.

Comment: Another form of the integral with a polynomial is : $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{4~dx}{P(x)^{1/4}}$ where $P(x)=x^2(x+2)^2(4Ax^2+2(B+4A)x+2A+2B+C))$

Comment: @JJacquelin, What substitution did you use for this?

Comment: The substitution is $\cosh(t)=x+1$, from : ${\int}_0^{\infty}\frac{4~dt}{\sqrt[{4}]{4A\cosh^2t+2B\cosh t+C-2A}}$