# A calculation that goes awfully wrong if we let $\pi=22/7$

Tags: numerical-methods, pi, estimation

Me and one of my friends had an argument and he said that using $22/7$ as value of $\pi$ is sufficient for any calculation. Can we always take it $22/7$, or is there some example of some calculation in which if we use $\pi=22/7$, some noticeable error which makes quite a significant difference, appears. Kind of calculative contradiction.

Thanks!

Comment: Fourier analysis, or any analysis which depends on cancelling trigonometric sums, would almost certainly go wrong- unless the value were corrected.

Comment: Relevant : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043192/how-come-pi-is-usually-approximated-as-3-14-or-22-7

Comment: In using such an approximation you are wrong by an amount of about $0.04$%. I think there is no difference with regard to any other approximation you can do in calculations.

Comment: Any function/algorithm with repeated need of the $\pi$ number or any function with chaotic behavior (Lorentz attractor) would be significantly affected by this approximation, most likely.

Comment: Circles would be regular $96$-gons if this were so.

Comment: $$\frac1{7\pi-22}$$

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838467/when-the-approximation-pi-simeq-3-14-is-not-sufficent

Answer (score 19):

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^4 (1-x)^4}{1+x^2} = \frac{22}{7}-\pi$$

That integral is clearly not zero.

Comment: but if Ii am using $\pi=22/7$ then it is zero..

Comment: "That integral is clearly not zero" ... because the integrand is positive on $(0,1)$.

Comment: ohh ok. Most def.

Comment: Someone's well-versed in Putnam Competition history.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80.

Answer (score 9):

Consider calculating the position of a satellite in a circular orbit about the earth. After a few hundred rotations, the satellite will be noticeably in the wrong place.

Comment: Interesting, I am just wondering if you could explain why this would take place? I mean why after several hundred rotations?

Comment: $22/7$ overestimate $\pi$ by around 0.04 percent. With one rotation, the error will be small and possibly not material. After say 100 rotations using $22/7$, one might have calculated the satellite to have returned to its original position, however it has over rotated by approx 4% of 360 degrees, or approx 14 degrees.

Answer (score 3):

> Compute the third decimal digit of $\pi$.

Perhaps even better, because it is as much wrong as it can be:

> Compute the ninth binary digit (in the fractional part) of $\pi$

Answer (score 2):

What quadrant is $1\ 000\ 000$ radians in?  The answer you get to that question is wrong if you use $22/7$ as an approximation to $\pi$.