# Computing $\tan\left(10^{100}\right)$ - what does it have to do with $100$-th digit of $\pi$?

Tags: contest-math, pi

Forgive me if my question is slightly *incorrect*.

I once saw a note, where it was stated that to compute $\tan\left(10^{100}\right)$ (by hand, without calculator) we need to know the $100$-th digit of $\pi$.

Is it true, and if it indeed is, how is this $100$-th number related to the task?

Comment: Does the digit of pi include $3$ befor the decimal point, or does it start with $1415...$? Because it is important.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you want to find $\tan(1000)$ by hand. Since you're Feynman and you're really smart you can do this fairly accurately for numbers in the interval $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$ but since the tangent function is periodic you can reduce it to that case by using that $1000-318\pi=0.973 \dotsb$ but if your approximation of $\pi$ were of by $10^{-3}$, say $3.141$ you would get $1000-318\times 3.141 = 1.161$ and since the error in the ratio of $\tan(1.161)$ and $\tan(0.973)$ is more than 10% you lost your bet.

Answer (score 2):

A user in the comments answers this in the following question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253910/the-integral-that-stumped-feynman).

To quote

> because the tangent function is periodic of period π, to know what the value is you need to know 10100modπ; this is effectively the same as knowing π to a hundred places`

edit: link to the answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/388972/26369)

Comment: Thank you! That's where I saw it.

Comment: It might be better to link the relevant answer directly: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/388972/26369

Comment: @MarkS. You're right, I edited in the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The digits needed are actually the 101st digit and 102nd digit after the decimal point of $1\over\pi$. These two digits happen to be "12" (courtesy of Wolframalpha) so $\tan\left(10^{100}\right)\approx\tan(0.12\pi)$.

To see why this works, let's follow the entire calculation:

Fetching the first 102 digits of $1\over\pi$ from Wolframalpha, we get:

0.318309886183790671537767526745028724068919291480912897495334688117793595268453070180227605532506171912... (note the "12" in the end)

So $10^{100}\over\pi$ is:

3183098861837906715377675267450287240689192914809128974953346881177935952684530701802276055325061719.12...

Which we will write as $N+0.12...$ (where $N$ is an integer).

Now we can write:

$\tan\left(10^{100}\right)=\tan\left[\left(10^{100}\over\pi\right)\cdot\pi\right]\approx\tan\left[\left(N+0.12\right)\cdot\pi\right]=\tan\left(N\pi+0.12\pi\right)$

And since $\tan(x)$ has a period of $\pi$, we get:

$\tan(N\pi+0.12\pi)=\tan(0.12\pi)$

Which can further be approximated as:

$\tan(0.12\pi)\approx\tan(0.38)\approx0.38$
(the last step uses the approximation of $\tan(x)\approx{x}$ for small $x$)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).